# I need help to print out between what prices the largest absolute difference occurred in the program. (I'm nearly finished.)

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I can't figure out the right way to update the prices during the if condition. It's probably really simple but I'm having trouble with it. Here is my code.

```
public class Change {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int days = 10;
        int largeDiff = 0; // largest difference
        int price2 = 0;
        int day1 = 1;
        int day2 = 2;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter stock prices:");

        int price1 = sc.nextInt();

        for (int i = 2; i <= days; i++) {
            price2 = sc.nextInt();
            int diff1 = Math.abs(price1 - price2);
            price1 = price2;

            if (diff1 > largeDiff) {
                largeDiff = diff1;
                day2 = i;
                day1 = day2 - 1;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Largest change of " + largeDiff);
        System.out.println("from " + price1 + " to " + price2);
        System.out.println("happened between day " + day1 + " and day " + day2);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your code printing and what do you expect it to print?

Comment: My code prints currently Largest change of (largest change) from the last price entered to the last price entered between (day 1) and (day2). Everything is correct except for the prices.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the line

```
System.out.println("from " + price1 + " to " + price2);
```

because by the end of your loop, `price1` and `price2` will both be just the last price entered.

What you need to do is when you store values for `largeDiff`, `day1` and `day2`, you should also store values for the two prices.  Then at the end of the loop, print those stored values instead of `price1` and `price2`.

```
price2 = sc.nextInt();
    int diff1 = Math.abs(price1 - price2);
    if (diff1 > largeDiff) {
        largeDiff = diff1;
        day2 = i;
        day1 = day2 - 1;
        storedPrice1 = price1;
        storedPrice2 = price2;
    }
    price1 = price2;

 }

 System.out.println("Largest change of " + largeDiff);
 System.out.println("from " + storedPrice1 + " to " + storedPrice2);
```

Comment: When I make these edits it only prints out between the second price in the largest change. For example:     Enter stock prices:
11
2
3
4
5
6
80
1
2
3
Largest change of 79
from 1 to 1
happened between day #7 and day #8

Comment: Did you move `price1 = price2;` to after the `if` block, as per my code?

Comment: Yes, and it still does the same thing.

Comment: It works when I run it. Are you sure you copied my code correctly?

Comment: I did the same thing. I added the variables storedPrice1 and storedPrice to into the if statement and after the if condition, I set price1 = price2. I changed the variables in the print statements too. It runs without any errors, but it doesn't print what I need it to.

Comment: I suggest you step through it with a debugger to see what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an array to store the values

```
 final int price1 = sc.nextInt();

 int[] prices = {price1, 0};
 int[] days = {day1, 0};

 for (int i = day2; i <= days; i++) {
    price2 = sc.nextInt();
    int newDiff = Math.abs(price1 - price2);
    if (newDiff > largeDiff) {
        largeDiff = newDiff;

        days[1] = i;

        prices[1] = price2;
    }

 }

 System.out.println("Largest change of " + largeDiff);
 System.out.println("from " + prices[0] + " to " + prices[1]);
 System.out.println("happened between day " + days[0] + " and day " + days[1]);
```

But I don't trust that loop over the days because if you wanted the largest price between all possible date pairs, you want something like

```
for (int day1 = 0; day1 <= days; day1++) {
    // Get day1 price 
    for (int day2 = 0; days2 <= days; day2++) {
        if (day1 == day2) continue; // skip the same day

        // Get day2 price
        // Get price between days
        // Check against largestDiff
            // Store diff, day1, day2, and the prices
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not allowed to use arrays in my solution.

Comment: Alright, well, same idea. Just two variables to update instead of one